# How to solve this tricky ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let,

$$
f(z) = \sum_i a_iz^i
$$

$$
g(z) = \sum_i b_iz^i
$$

How can I solve the following ODE?

$$
z\left(\frac{df(z)}{dz} + \frac{dg(z)}{dz} \right) - (f(z) + g(z)) = 0
$$

I have tried to convert this to a standard form, but I can't progress. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why are $f$ and $g$ split at all? The sum is of exactly the same form, so the problem is just $zy'-y=0$. This is first order linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ian proposed substitute $y(z) = f(z)+g(z)$ to get the differential equation

$$zy'-y=0 \implies y'=y/z \implies dy/y = dz/z$$
$$\implies \ln|y|-\ln|y_0| = \ln|z|-\ln|z_0|$$
$$\implies |y|=\left|\dfrac{y_0}{z_0}z\right|$$
$$\implies y = cz$$